# Concatenate/Merge two prettified json strings in Rust

Tags: rust, serde

I have two strings that are derived from serde from two different sources

JSON String 1

```
let a: String = 
"
{
  "A": 100
}
";
```

JSON String 2

```
let b: String =
"
{
  "B": "aA"
}
";
```

I would like to concatenate these two strings to 1 single json prettified string `new_string` which can be displayed like as follows:-

```
println!("{}", new_string)
Result:- 
{
  "A": 100,
  "B": "aA"
}
```

I tried concatenating them using vectors but whenever I print
them I get newline characters which I want to avoid.Is this possible in Rust using serde.

Answer (score 2):

In their current form as strings, it would be rather difficult to properly combine arbitrary JSON values.

Instead, you need to deserialize those strings into workable values, combine them, then serialize the final value back to a string:

```rust
use serde_json::Value;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let a = r#"
{
  "A": 100
}
"#;

    let b = r#"
{
  "B": "aA"
}
"#;

    let mut data_a: HashMap<String, Value> = serde_json::from_str(a).unwrap();
    let mut data_b: HashMap<String, Value> = serde_json::from_str(b).unwrap();

    data_a.extend(data_b);

    let result = serde_json::to_string_pretty(&data_a).unwrap();
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

Ideally, you wouldn't even serialize values to strings in the first place. Whatever values you get from your "two different sources" might also be possible to either combine directly, or be serialized into a `serde_json::Value` that you can work with.

Comment: I ended up using the crate `json_value_merge` for solving the problem.